# How to Screencast an Unity App from Oculus Go?

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine, oculus

I am trying to enable screencast in my Unity App which I have developed for my Oculus Go(Android). 
I am unable to find any solutions to add permissions for screen casting to the AndroidManifest.xml file or enable screencast from Unity.

Comment: unhelpful options - the oculus phone app screencasting for mobile headset non-unity apps and the cli tool for rift unity apps: https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/pcsdk/latest/concepts/dg-compositor-mirror/

Comment: Is that possible to create client server communication between Oculus and another android app and share screen casting to android app ?